# How to bind ienumerable list from a csv query param in a Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am sending an array over an ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `${rootUrl}api/groups/EditMemberGroups?groupIds=${userGroupIds}`,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

And the Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void EditMemberGroups(IEnumerable<int> groupIds)
{
    GroupMemberService.EditMemberGroups(groupIds);
}
```

The problem is when it gets to this api call the `groupIds` is null. The Call looks like this: `http://localhost/api/groups/EditMemberGroups?groupIds=1,2,3`

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class that will contain the list:

```
public class ListOfGroupIds
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GroupIds { get; set; }
}
```

Change your end-point to:

```
public void EditMemberGroups([FromBody] ListOfGroupIds anyNameHere)
```

Send the data as a JSON object:

```
data: { 'GroupIds': groupIds }
```

Comment: Tried this already and it gives me the same result. `groupIds` is null

Comment: I corrected the definition of the end-point function. Try putting `[FromBody] ` in front of the parameter.

Comment: Did you change the footprint of the ajax call so the IDs are not in the url but in a separate data property? 
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: '${rootUrl}api/groups/EditMemberGroups', data: { 'GroupIds': groupIds }});

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: If you change the parameter in the end-point to be a single string, do you receive anything when you send it this way `/api/groups/EditMemberGroups?groupIds=ABC`?

Comment: This worked. My issue was that I had another param in the function so I took it out and added it to the `ListOfGroupIds` class and boom it worked like a charm. Thanks @miro-J

Answer (score 0):

You have to change two things in your code. First you have to add the `[FromQuery]` attribute to specify that this values comes from the query instead of the post body.

```
public void EditMemberGroups([FromQuery]IEnumerable<int> groupIds)
```

The second change is in the API call itself. You have to send the data like this:

`http://localhost/api/groups/EditMemberGroups?groupIds=1&groupIds=2&groupIds=3`